# Linux Mint: Dislocker command not found

Tags: linux-mint

I'm trying to decrypt a Bitlocked drive on Linux Mint 19.1 through Dislocker.

I tried

```
sudo dislocker /dev/sda6 -u<password> -- /media/Softs
```

but the terminal says

```
[9] 10532
--: command not found
```

I believe I'm running the latest version of dislocker - v0.7.1.

Comment: Use full path to invoke the command.

Comment: Does your password contain quotes or semi-colons, parentheses, or other characters that would be interpreted as special by the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the -p command instead of the -u. -p takes the recovery key, not the password.

```
sudo dislocker /dev/sda6 -p000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000 -- /media/Softs
```